# Strange shadows in Eevee orthographic camera

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows, orthographic

If I use Cicles engine everything looks great (obviously). I try **Eevee** engine with **perspective camera** mode, and result also fine. But I need ortho projection. If I switch to **Eevee + orthographical camera** the shadows are absolutely terrible, here you can see.

[image]

I use (and need) Sun-light, and try increase Shadows Cascade Size to max value 4096, and result is still awfull:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?
Blender 2.93.3

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Blender manual knows everything, lol. If you have the same problem you need to decrease the Clip End value for your orthographic camera. Its all because of the way Sun-light Cascading Shadows work. My default Clip End value was 1000, too big. With the 200 value the shadow rendering started to look fine.

[image]